# Header HTML tag with fixed positioning not working in IOS versions <=12 phone/tablets

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header which doesn't work on IOS versions <=12 The header scrolls up with the page and does not stay fixed. I am using the header html element and have add the below css. I have tried numerous suggestions found but nothing seems to be working.

```
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
  min-height: 90px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to your CSS file:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 3;
top: 0px;
min-height: 90px;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this also but didn't' work.